# Biggest parallel text and speech corpus

Tags: nlp

What is the biggest parallel text and speech corpus. By that I mean a corpus in which for each sentence, there exists a (or more) pronunciation (speech).

Answer (score 1):

The biggest corpus is probably... Google's! But if you want access, you'll need to call your Chinese hacker friends.

More seriously, the WSJ1 has about 100 hours of speech http://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC94S13A